# How to delete docker image by both date and tag

Tags: image, docker, filter

I'd like to delete docker images older than 7 days which also do not have a `latest` tag

`docker image prune` has a filter by date option

`docker images` has a filter by reference option which can be used to filter by tag

However there doesn't seem to be a way of combining both filters

An alternative I'd prefer not to have to use is by pushing the output of `docker images` through a `grep`, `sed` or `awk` command as that seems a bit fragile if the format changes.

Is there another way I've missed?

Comment: `docker images -q` will just print out the ID of each matching image, and I'd expect that to be a fairly stable output format.  (I still do `docker images -q ... | xargs docker rmi` routinely, even though there's `docker image prune` now.)

Comment: yeah getting the ID is fine, it's filtering the images that's my problem, I've found the format option but it still requires date manipulation to compare against the current date time